# wrong mint fee and unknown token in wallet

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, candy-machine

I just completed the candy machine ui setup from the metaplex repo

But When i try to mint, the wrong fee comes up, mint should be 1 sol.
When i go ahead, I get a success message but an unknown token in the wallet

PS. I'm not minting with treasury wallet.

[image: Wallet confirmation - mint fee]

```
REACT_APP_CANDY_MACHINE_ID=Fz9WxfPa126y8voGyaF2qAfDJMktauxWmnKYnMm7a1fj
```

I can confirm that mint works from command line using this command:

```
ts-node ~/metaplex/js/packages/cli/src/candy-machine-v2-cli.ts mint_one_token
-e devnet
-k ~/.config/solana/devnet.json
-c example
```

Please see my Config

```
{
"price": 1.0,
"number": 10,
"gatekeeper": null,
"solTreasuryAccount": "redacted",
"splTokenAccount": null,
"splToken": null,
"goLiveDate": "16 Jun 2022 18:50:00 GMT",
"endSettings": null,
"whitelistMintSettings": null,
"hiddenSettings": null,
"storage": "arweave-sol",
"ipfsInfuraProjectId": null,
"ipfsInfuraSecret": null,
"nftStorageKey": null,
"awsS3Bucket": null,
"noRetainAuthority": false,
"noMutable": false
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check ur Candy Machine txs and you get bot taxs on both Mint instructions.

The error says `> Program log: Missing set collection during mint IX for Candy Machine with collection set, Candy Machine Botting is taxed at 10000000 lamports`. To avoid this make sure to use the latest version of the official Metaplex Mint UI [`candy-machine-ui`](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/tree/master/js/packages/candy-machine-ui) because its seems that you are using an outdated version of the UI or an unofficial UI that doesnt support collections.